# PHP IOS Push Notification ( Permission Denied )

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I've been looking since last night for an answer to this but it seemed I couldn't find anyone that was having the exact same problem.  Similar but not it.  I'm trying to connect to Apples APNS through a stream_socket_client.  I'm working this in a LAMP environment and have port 2195 open.  My errorString says **( Permission denied )**.  My trouble is finding people who've posted much of anything about this error.  The warning I'm getting from the error reporting is **Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Permission denied)**

As for the good stuff.  I wrote a class to handle this push notification.  Here's the unfinshed method to set the connection.

```
 public function setConnection() {

        $apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
        $apnsPort = 2195;
        $apnsCert = '../model/apns-dev.pem';

        $streamContext = stream_context_create();
        stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
        stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', "********");
        stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', true);

        $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://'.$apnsHost.':'. $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 20, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT , $streamContext);

    }
```

To me this looks right but obviously, something that's not right.

Answer (score 3):

It's a SELinux Conf

The problem turned out to be the `httpd_can_network_connect` SELinux setting that is on by default in Fedora 12.

In a shell console, run as root:

```
/usr/sbin/setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

reference: http://www.rkrishardy.com/2009/12/permission-denied-13-when-opening-socket-in-php-apache/

Comment: I can't confirm this being correct at the moment being this issue is 3 years old.

Answer (score 0):

The simplepush.php code in the following tutorial worked well for me.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
```

Comment: It was actually a server problem with the openssl I think.  I change some configurations and it works now.  Thanks for the heads up.  oh and don't use the verify_peer option either.

Comment: @TimLieberman what you change in your server, Please write here so i can check my configuration also. thanks

Comment: @Ron I don't remember what the issue was or how we solved this.  I apologize I should've updated this question when I found out.